# error when using `get` within a dplyr mutate statement in R

Tags: r, dplyr, typeof

I have my R environment with some objects in it.

```
tmp <- list(1,2,4)
dafa <- data.frame(thing="Yes", 
            value=4)
```

Lists and Dataframes both come up as `list` when using:

```
typeof(get("tmp"))  # list
typeof(get("dafa")) # list
```

I want to get a dataframe of all the objects in my environment and note whether some of them are dataframes or not using `inherits(get(name), "data.frame")`

```
library(tidyverse)
# get a list of all the objects in the environment and 
# store in a table
data_items <- map_dfr(ls(), \(itm){
    data.frame(name=itm, 
               type=typeof(get(itm)), 
               size=object.size(get(itm)))})

# adjust each row to specify if object is a dataframe
data_items %>% rowwise() %>%
mutate(type = ifelse(inherits(get(name), "data.frame"),
                   "data.frame",
                   type))
```

However, this complains:

> Error in get(name) : first argument has length > 1

Even though it's `rowwise`, any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're using `dplyr::mutate` and not `plyr::mutate`? This is the sort of problem a name conflict could cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
data.frame(name = ls(),
           class = sapply(mget(ls()), class))
#      name      class
# dafa dafa data.frame
# tmp   tmp       list
```

A comparable `tidyverse` solution would be:

```r
library(purrr)

tibble(name = ls(envir = .GlobalEnv),
       class = map_chr(mget(name, envir = .GlobalEnv), class))
#   name  class     
#   <chr> <chr>     
# 1 dafa  data.frame
# 2 tmp   list
```

---

I want to point out that this works on this simplistic example, but often objects have multiple classes, which would cause an error with this code. Using something like `is.data.frame` would be helpful here, but the approach is dependent on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: that's much neater! any idea why mine is failing?

Comment: Yes, `get` only takes one element at a time. You are passing it a character vector. To get multiple objects, use `mget`.

Comment: but doesn't rowwise just pass a vector of length 1?

Comment: Your code is also giving me: "Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 4, 2, 3"

Comment: Your posted code works for me. Can you try running only your posted code in a fresh R session and see if you get that error?

Comment: From scratch, it gives:

Error in `dplyr::mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `type = ifelse(inherits(mget(name), "data.frame"), "data.frame", type)`.
Caused by error:
! value for ‘dafa’ not found

Comment: Make sure you run the first code block too (e.g. `dafa <-` and `tmp <-`)

Comment: strange, it's working now! Might have been the scoping with the .GlobalEnv